# Disable Kendo Chart Tooltip Animations

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I want to get rid of the silly tooltip animation that slides the tooltip from one bar to another.  It updates the tooltip instantly but lingers on the previous bar.  I have tried the documenations transitions property on both the chart and the tooltip and neither has an affect.

```
$('.chart').kendoChart({
    transitions: false,
    series: [{
        name: "Gold Medals",
        data: [current.data("compliant-count")],
        color: "#f3ac32"
    }, {
        name: "Silver Medals",
        data: [current.data("noncompliant-count")],
        color: "#b8b8b8"
    },
    tooltip: {
         visible: true,
         template: "#= series.name #: #= value #",
         transitions: false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `transitions` configuration option only applies to the chart itself (bars etc.).
You can disable the animation for the tooltip like this:

```
var chart = $('#chart').kendoChart({
    transitions: false,
    series: [{
        name: "Gold Medals",
        data: [current.data("compliant-count")],
        color: "#f3ac32"
    }, {
        name: "Silver Medals",
        data: [current.data("noncompliant-count")],
        color: "#b8b8b8"
    },
    tooltip: {
         visible: true,
         template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
    }
}).data("kendoChart");
chart._tooltip.options.animation.duration = 0;
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/MuXS2/))

You can achieve the same for all chart tooltips by changing the default options before creating the charts:

```
kendo.dataviz.Tooltip.fn.options.animation.duration = 0;
```

Completely eliminating the effect of the content changing before the tooltip is moved would require changes in the source code of `kendo.dataviz.Tooltip`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just come by the same issue, and discovered that simply adding

```
animation: {
  duration: 0
}
```

under the `tooltip` section of the chart config does the job